# Simple formula for $H_n = m + \alpha $?

Tags: closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions, harmonic-numbers, digamma-function

Let $H_i$ be the $i$ th harmonic number.
For a given positive integer $m$ we want to find the smallest possible positive integer value $n$ such that $H_n = m + \alpha $, where $\alpha > 0$.

Let us define the solution as $f(m) = n$

Let $\operatorname{floor}$ be defined as rounding downwards.
Examples $\operatorname{floor}(3,14) = 3 , \operatorname{floor}(9,99999) = 9 $)

Let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Now it appears that $f(m) $ has a simple closed form :

$$ f(m) = \operatorname{floor}\left( \exp(n - \gamma) - \frac{1}{2} \right) $$

How to prove this ?
I assume it is necessary to assume $\gamma$ is irrational ?

I toyed around with irrationality measure and asymptotics to the digamma function.
But nothing worked.

Maybe use Fourier series ?

Comment: $\gamma$ is not known to be irrational

Comment: I know that, that is Why I said “ assume “.

Comment: Im sorry Peter but it does not follow from that in a trivial sense. Floor 30,99 =\= Floor 31,01 If you Get What I mean ...

Comment: @mick, I understand. Would it be possible to elaborate on why we need to assume that it's irrational? Because if it's required, then to prove the formula we would need to prove the irrationality first, which as you know, is not trivial at all

Comment: It was Just an intuïtive guess. I have No proof that we need the irrationality of $\gamma$.

Comment: However many statements relating Floor and fibonacci depend on the irrationality of the golden Number ( or it could be used or derived ).

Comment: @mick A good point. But I do not think that the irrationality of $\gamma$ plays a role. If it does however, a proof will be extremely difficult (perhaps impossible)

Comment: Maybe this formula could help ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5058/formula-for-the-harmonic-series-h-n-sum-k-1n-1-k-due-to-gregorio-fontana?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a program which calculated a few first values $f(m)$ and [plug them to OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C4%2C11%2C31%2C83%2C227%2C616%2C1674%2C4550&language=english&go=Search). The search query point me to sequence [A002387](https://oeis.org/A002387), and your question turned out to be well-known. I copied below the comments from OEIS

> For $k\ge 1$, $$\log(k + 1/2) + \gamma < H_k< \log(k + 1/2) + \gamma + 1/(24k^2),$$ where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant ([A001620](https://oeis.org/A001620)). It is likely that the upper and lower bounds have the same floor for all $k\ge2$, in which case $a(n) = \lfloor \exp(n-\gamma) + 1/2\rfloor$ for all $n\ge 0$.
> This remark is based on a simple heuristic argument. The lower and upper bounds differ by $1/(24k^2)$, so the probability that there's an integer between the two bounds is $1/(24k^2)$. Summing that over all $k\ge 2$ gives the expected number of values of $k$ for which there's an integer between the bounds. That sum equals $\pi^2/144 - 1/24 \approx 0.02687$. That's much less than $1$, so it is unlikely that there are any such values of $k$. – [Dean Hickerson](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Dean_Hickerson), Apr 19 2003

So, if the conjecture fails then a counterexample is expected to be at the beginning of the infinity.  :-) Robert G. Wilson v, and T. D. Noe provided a [table of $n$, $a(n)$ for $n = 0..2303$](https://oeis.org/A002387/b002387.txt), so if the conjecture holds for these $n$ then
the heuristic probability of its failure falls to about $1/(24\cdot 2303)$.

> Referring to [A118050](https://oeis.org/A118050) and [A118051](https://oeis.org/A118050), using a few terms of the asymptotic series for the inverse of $H(x)$, we can get an expression which, with greater likelihood than mentioned above, should give $a(n)$ for all $n\ge 0$. For example, using the same type of heuristic argument given by Dean Hickerson, it can be shown that, with probability $> 99.995%$, we should have, for all $n\ge 0$, $$a(n) = \lfloor u + 1/2 - 1/(24u) + 3/(640u^3)\rfloor$$ where $u = e^{n - \gamma}$. - David W. Cantrell (DWCantrell(AT)sigmaxi.net)

Comment: Cool. Gotta love OEIS.

Comment: Although not a solution to the conjecture I guess I have to accept since it is an open conjecture.
It is a nice answer afterall.
I hope this gets proven fast.
Inform me when it is proven please :)