# Is there a closed form for $ 1+ \sum_{m=1}^{2(n-1)} \prod_{k=1}^{m} \frac{2(n-1)-(k-1)}{( ^nC_2 -k)} $?

Tags: combinatorics

Can there be a closed form representation for the expression

$$ 1+ \sum_{m=1}^{2(n-1)} \prod_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac{2(n-1)-(k-1)}{( ^nC_2 -k)} $$

It would simplify working with some equations I have. The current form in its full expansion is way too cumbersome.

Comment: What is $^nC_2$?

Comment: Did you not find the answers to your previous question helpful?

Comment: yes i did. sorry about this one, had another expression which was posing a bit of a problem for me, and not this. Lets call this a copying error. thankyou anyway.

Comment: @Hemantika: You can try posting another question.

Comment: Please don't have titles that consist of nothing but Markup/$\LaTeX$. Also, a big expression is not a very informative title.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111816/1102) to your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111803/evaluate-1-sum-i-0n-2-prod-k-0i-n-k-r-k).

Setting $N = 2(n-1)$ and $r = \binom{n}{2} - 1$, what we have is

$$ 1 + \sum_{m=1}^{N} \frac{\binom{N}{m}}{\binom{r}{m}}$$

In your previous question, we had shown that

$$ 1 + \sum_{m=1}^{N-1} \frac{\binom{N}{m}}{\binom{r}{m}} = \frac{r+1}{r-N+1} - \frac{1}{\binom{r}{N}}$$

Thus what you seek is:

$$ \frac{r+1}{r-N+1}$$

where $r$ and $N$ were defined above.