# 1Prove that limit n tends to infinity $1 + 2 \sum_{k=0}^n1/\binom{n}{k} = e^2$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

Prove that limit n tends to infinity $1 + 2 \sum_{k=0}^n1/\binom{n}{k} = e^2$

I have not been able to proceed ..tried many things like ratio of nck and nc(k+1)...also opened it.!! Not able to slove.!!

Comment: Does $\sum_{k=0}^n/\binom{n}{k}$ imply $\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac1{\binom nk}$?

Comment: Does $/\binom{n}{k}$ mean $1/\binom{n}{k} = \frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!}$?

Comment: yes....!!! i meant that only.!!

Comment: I don't believe it is true: have you written it correctly?

Comment: ya.!!!i have writen it correctly..!!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151441/calculate-sums-of-inverses-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true.

Binomial coefficients are smallest when $k$ takes on the smallest or largest values possible, and they grow very fast as $k$ moves towards the middle.

Correspondingly, the reciprocals show the opposite pattern. Most of the terms of the sum are completely negligible!

In fact, for $k \in [2, n-2]$, we always have

$$\binom{n}{k} \geq \frac{n(n-1)}{2} $$

and therefore

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + 1 \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}
\leq 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} \frac{2}{n(n-1)} $$

and therefore

$$ 2 + \frac{2}{n} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}
\leq 2 + \frac{2}{n} + (n-3) \cdot \frac{2}{n(n-1)} $$

from which we can see that all three terms must converge to $2$ as $n \to \infty$.