# Solving a limit involving binomial coefficients

Tags: limits

> If $$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n\choose i}$$
> then find $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$$

I tried to solve it by using sandwich theorem and obtained following relation

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n\choose 0}+\frac{1}{n\choose n}}\geq \frac{1}{a_n}\geq0$$

The first inequality is obtained using the fact that $$\frac{1}{n\choose 0}+\frac{1}{n\choose n}\leq \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n\choose i}$$

This gives $$0.5\geq L \geq 0$$

The answer is $0.5$ only , however I am not able to prove that $$\frac{1}{a_n}\geq 0.5$$

How to continue?

Comment: Hint: $a_n\geq \frac{n}{{n \choose \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}}$.

Comment: You already showed $0.5 \ge 1/a_n$ for each $n \ge 2.$ If you were to show the reverse inequality, it would mean that $1/a_n$ (and thus also $a_n$) was constant for $n \ge 2.$ But it is not.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/776558/305862) obtained using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: @AnCar I am not able to see how does that helps

Comment: @coffeemath Hmm, Yes you are right , I need to look for some $f(n)$ such that $\frac{1}{a_n}\geq f(n)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0.5$

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes the answer helps me, thanks for helping  :-)