# is there a general identity for $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{{n \choose r}} $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

is there a general identity for $$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{{n \choose r}} $$

**My Approach**

I tried to write $\frac{1}{{n \choose r}}$ as $$\frac{n+1}{{n+2}} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{{n+1 \choose r+1}}+ \frac{1}{{n+1 \choose r}} $$ but couldn't get any further as I wasn't able to make a telescopic sum which would cancel out.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305096/42969 ? – Found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Br%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cfrac%7Br%7D%7B%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20r%7D%7D%24)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finite sum with inverse binomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305096/finite-sum-with-inverse-binomial)