trying to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^{-1} = \frac{n+1}{2^{(n+1)}} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{2^k}{k}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^{-1} = \frac{n+1}{2^{(n+1)}} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{2^k}{k}$$
I think this is a fascinatig equality.
I have tried to use this equation first:
$${n \choose k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_{0}^{1} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}~ dx$$
$(n+1)$s are cancelled at both sides:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}^{-1}= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}~ dx$$
how to apply change of variables so that we can compute
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$$
$x = \sin^2{t} , dx = \sin{2t}dt$ didnt work for me. I have no clue about how to deal with the right  side of the equality

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Does this answer your question?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151441/calculate-sums-of-inverses-of-binomial-coefficients
